# WordPress get by and exclude by meta data messes pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

So this is my first post and wow, I didn't know this site existed. I've had a look around at questions and I hope that mine isnt a dumb nooby one. Although I am a noob :S

Ok, so I created a function in WordPress that will add a meta box to the new posts page so that I can specify whether or not this post should be featured (I read this is better than creating a featured category for SEO purposes?).

Anyway.. The code I have works in showing the most recent. Here is the code for that:

```
<?php
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  $custom = get_post_meta($my_query->post->ID, '_featuredpost_meta_value_key', true);
if (  $custom ){
?>
<article class="container" itemprop="blogPosts" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 itemprop="about">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>two-thirds column<?php } else {?> twelve columns  <?php } ?>">
            <p class="post-excerpt"><?php  modified_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
        <div class="one-third column">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class'=>'hide-mobile')); ?> 
        </div>
    <?php } ?>      
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button button-primary">Continue Reading</a>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <div class="post-info">
        <ul>
            <li class="date"><?php the_date();?></li>
            <li class="author"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/questions/user/<?php echo get_the_author_meta('user_login'); ?>"><?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name'); ?></a></li>
            <li class="category"><?php the_category(', '); ?></li>
            <li class="tags"><?php the_tags('',', ',''); ?></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</article>
  <?php
}
endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

Now, When I use the same code below, but then use:

```
 if ( ! $custom ){
```

to show the posts that are not set to be featured that also works. The problem is that the pagination no longer works. When I go to the second page it just duplicates what is on the home page.

This leads me to believe that I have created a mashed together crappy bit of code. Can someone please help me build a loop, that will exclude any posts where  the meta data **_featuredpost_meta_value_key** is set to **Yes**.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a WP Meta Query in your original `$args` array.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

From the docs, here's an example:

```
    $meta_query_args = array(
        'relation' => 'OR', // Optional, defaults to "AND"
        array(
            'key'     => '_my_custom_key',
            'value'   => 'Value I am looking for',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    );
    $meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );
```

But you can also use the sugar provided by the WP_Query class and pass it in as the `meta_query` value to your original args:

```
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
      'meta_query' => array(
        'key'     => '_featuredpost_meta_value_key',
        'value'   => 'Yes',
        'compare' => '='
      )
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.